# Convert textual table to html table using flask/jinja2/javascript

Tags: python, jinja2, markdown

I have this flask code:

```
mytext = """Here's some text and a table.

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 26 |
| Amy | 29 |

And here's some more text.
"""
import markdown
mytext = markdown.markdown(mytext)
return render_template('my_template.html', mytext=mytext)
```

my_template.html content:

```
<div>{{ chat_response | safe }}</div>
```

I get an output like this one:

```
Here's some text and a table:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 26 |
| Amy | 29 |

And here's some more text.
```

But I can't make the table "convert" to an actual table instead of this text. What I'm after is using some rich text I guess (Stack Overflow is doing this automatically)

Here's some text and a table:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 26 |
| Amy | 29 |

And here's some more text.

I believe there's a super simple way to achieve this, as the initial text is some kind of a markup language that should be able to convert to a table. Instead of using a cumbersome javascript or flask code, there should be something simpler, but I'm unable to find it.

Comment: It looks like maybe you want a Markdown parser with table support. There are probably several options out there. Those search terms should help you find something.

Comment: @larsks - thanks for your comment. For anyone else asking the same question, I resolved this by using a parser called Misaka. I'll add more details in the answer once I get to my computer to copy the working code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem:

```
from flask_misaka import Misaka
misaka = Misaka(app, tables=True, wrap=True, escape=True, no_intra_emphasis=True, hard_wrap=True)


my_text = misaka.render(my_text)
 return my_text
```

And then, I added the table styling to my css:

```
<style>

table {
  border-collapse: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1.1px solid black;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

th {
  background-color: #3f4d67;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

</style>
```

That's it. I get a nice table now.